# Is is possible without knowing structure to make hdf5 file that will be the same copy of another one in python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, hdf5

If I have one hdf5 file `f1.h5` and I want to make a copy of this file to another one (e.g. `f2.h5`), but I don't know the structure of `f1.h5` and I want to copy it automatically, can I do it with some tips of `h5py`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `.copy()` method to recursively copy objects from `f1.h5` to `f2.h5`. You don't need to know the schema: use keys to access groups/datasets at the root level.  If the source is a Group object, by default all objects within that group will be copied recursively.

```
import h5py
h5r=h5py.File("f1.h5", 'r')
with h5py.File("f2.h5", 'w') as h5w:
    for obj in h5r.keys():        
        h5r.copy(obj, h5w )       
h5r.close()
```

Comment: There is a similar answer here: [How to copy a dataset object with h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53462953/10462884)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about h5py, but it should be possible by:

```
f1=open('f1.h5','rb')
f2=open('f2.h5','wb')

f2.write(f1.read())
```

You read each byte of the first file and write it to the second file. Things such as structure don't matter

Comment: I am not sure that it is possible to use with files that have fields to acces to daaset.

But I'll try this, thanx

Comment: @b2f, will this work for any size file? Frequently HDF5 files are larger than system RAM, so users work with subsets of data.